# IPSec Tunnel in a tunnel? A soon to be travelling remote worker

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tunnel, ipsec

Ok. I generally work remotely, which is nice. I soon plan to do some overseas travelling, and I would prefer to hide my real srcIP if possible (potential audits/geo-restrictions, etc.).

I'm reasonable confident I can run the following topology:

1. OpenVPN, terminated to my router (from a popular provider), with a remote exit point in the US.
2. IPSec tunnel (Cisco AnyConnect) on the laptop, connecting over aforementioned router.

I believe I've done this in the past (or did I just dream it), so I think it should be fine. If not, please correct me here.

My more pressing concern is overhead/latency. Not sure what kind of bandwidth I'll have available from across the Atlantic. Ideally (I think) an 'unencrypted Tunnel' would best suit my needs: masking the real source IP without the increased latency of the redundant encryption...

But on the other hand, in the process of encrypting the packets, there is some level of compression as well to offset, but just how much? 2 steps forward, 2.5 steps back???

I hope you guys see where I'm going with this. An 'VPN-ish' solution with compression enabled and encryption disabled...well that'd be pretty good.

I love this site, but haven't had a worthwhile question, one that I couldn't figure out on my own...until now.

let me know what you think...

Comment: Cisco AnyConnect is more than just a vpn client. It’s a security product. It has numerous quirks. This sounds questionable at best, but might be possible. Can you turn off split tunneling in AnyConnect? There won’t be any purpose for a second VPN after that. Problem with AnyConnect is that the settings are controlled by your IT admin usually from their end.

Comment: well, it's not a split tunneling thing here, but a tunnel within another tunnel. Basically I'm wondering if I'd get better performance connecting over (1) a standard OpenVPN setup...(2) an OpenVPN tunnel with Encryption disabled...or (3) some other as yet unknown option. It's strictly an exercise in hiding the SrcIP here.

Comment: I fully understand what you are asking. I’m suggesting that what you are asking is not necessary. One VPN is all you need. Let me ask you this. Why is it you think your openvpn setup is going to hide your IP address but your AnyConnect setup is not? Neither one of them will, or both of them will. It’s all a matter of split-tunneling being on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, Odd Apple. My goal here, ultimately, is simply to mask my geo-location when connecting to the corporate network, nothing more. Very much like the use case of VPN'ing back to the states to access streaming media whilst abroad.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Your post does not clearly indicate you want to hide your location from your employer. Which is why I asked why the employers VPN was not already good enough. Why not just try it and let us know how you did it.

Comment: That was the stated goal in the opening sentence. Anyway, I will of course be trying it. I was just hoping for some Ex Ante feedback; this board is usually pretty good. My real question was if the Pro's of disabling encryption would outweigh the Con's of the corresponding loss of compression.